# The provided host name is not valid for this server

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to migrate a drupal website from a server into my localhost but I trigger the error

> The provided host name is not valid for this server.

I've seen I need to add the trusted host pattern, but looks like this is not working I still get the error

My server is run on port 9000

```
sudo php -S 127.0.0.1:9000
```

My trusted hosts, and I've no Vhost

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^serverStuffWeDontMind$',
  '^localhost\:9000$',
  '^127\.0\.0\.1\:9000$',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the port number is causing your issue; try with simply

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^serverStuffWeDontMind$',
  '^localhost$',
  '^127\.0\.0\.1$',
);
```

The purpose of setting trusted hosts is preventing HTTP Host Header attacks, which all come down to pointing another domain to your IP and making use of that. Ports are not the part of this equation as far as I know.

Take a look at Drupal 8 Docs on [Trusted hosts](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install/trusted-host-settings) and this [article](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/automated-detection-of-host-header-attacks/) on Accunetix.

Answer (score 0):

You need create a virtualhost in apache2

DocumentRoot /your/project/route/
    ServerName localhost

```
<Directory "/your/project/route">
  AllowOverride All
```